# Having difficulty importing Dataset into ssms (SQL sevre Import and Export Wizard)

Tags: ssms, data-import, ssms-2016

Need help, been trying to import a dataset into ssms after creating a table, but i keep getting the error message (attached image).

Error message.......TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
The operation could not be completed. The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, you've not installed the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider on the machine doing the importing (in the correct "bitness"). There's not really a lot more we can tell you, other than install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in the "bitness" (x64/x86) you need on the device.